# What does value & 0xff do in Java?

Tags: java, integer, byte, bitwise-and

I have the following Java code:

```
byte value = 0xfe; // corresponds to -2 (signed) and 254 (unsigned)
int result = value & 0xff;
```

The result is 254 when printed, but I have no idea how this code works. If the `&` operator is simply bitwise, then why does it not result in a byte and instead an integer?

Comment: I copy the code to Eclipse. It warn me "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte". Should it change to int value = 0xfe;

Comment: @BenCheng should be `byte value = (byte) 0xfe;`

Answer (score 192, accepted):

It sets `result` to the (unsigned) value resulting from putting the 8 bits of `value` in the lowest 8 bits of `result`.

The reason something like this is necessary is that `byte` is a signed type in Java. If you just wrote:

```
int result = value;
```

then `result` would end up with the value `ff ff ff fe` instead of `00 00 00 fe`. A further subtlety is that the `&` is defined to operate only on `int` values<sup>1</sup>, so what happens is:

1. `value` is promoted to an `int` (`ff ff ff fe`).
2. `0xff` is an `int` literal (`00 00 00 ff`).
3. The `&` is applied to yield the desired value for `result`.

(The point is that conversion to `int` happens *before* the `&` operator is applied.)

1<sub>Well, not quite. The `&` operator works on `long` values as well, if either operand is a `long`. But not on `byte`. See the Java Language Specification, sections [15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) and [5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).</sub>

Comment: What does the x mean in that notation? x isn't a number or a hex number?

Comment: @KazRodgers - The `0x` (or `0X`) prefix tells Java that the integer literal that follows should be interpreted as hex (base 16). Java also supports a bare `0` prefix for octal literals and a `0b` (or `0B`) prefix for binary literals. See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) for more info in integer literals.

Comment: The literal that follows? So for example if I had 0x3fa. The 3fa is the part being translated into a literal number and 0x is noting out "this is a hex number"? @TedHopp?

Comment: @KazRodgers - Exactly. Note that `0x` or `0b` by itself (without any digits following) is illegal syntax in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So this is basically an `Integer.valueOf(byte)` if such a function existed? Also, do you know why `int result = value;` results in `ff ff ff fe`?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky - The hex bit pattern `fe` in 8-bit, two's complement corresponds to the decimal value −2. To preserve the value, `Integer.valueOf(byte)` would need to produce `ff ff ff fe` (−2 in 32-bit, two's complement), not `00 00 00 fe` (decimal value 254). This transformation (from a `byte` value `fe` to an `int` value `ff ff ff fe`) is known as [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) and is part of the Java language specification. The purpose of `value & 0xff` is to undo the sign extension (i.e., to simulate zero extension, something Java doesn't have).

Answer (score 68):

From http://www.coderanch.com/t/236675/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/xff

The hex literal 0xFF is an equal int(255). Java represents int as 32 bits. It look like this in binary:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
```

When you do a bit wise AND with this value(255) on any number, it is going to mask(make ZEROs) all but the lowest 8 bits of the number (will be as-is).

```
... 01100100 00000101 & ...00000000 11111111 = 00000000 00000101
```

& is something like % but not [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator).

**And why 0xff?** this in ((power of 2) - 1).
All ((power of 2) - 1) (e.g 7, 255...) will behave something like % operator.

Then
In binary, 0 is, all zeros, and 255 looks like this:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
```

And -1 looks like this

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

When you do a bitwise AND of 0xFF and any value from 0 to 255, the result is the exact same as the value. And if any value higher than 255 still the result will be within 0-255.

However, if you do:

```
-1 & 0xFF
```

you get

`00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`, which does NOT equal the original value of -1 (`11111111` is 255 in decimal).

> Few more bit manipulation: (Not related to the question)

```
X >> 1 = X/2
X << 1 = 2X
```

**Check any particular bit is set(1) or not (0) then**

```
 int thirdBitTobeChecked =   1 << 2   (...0000100)
 int onWhichThisHasTobeTested = 5     (.......101)

 int isBitSet = onWhichThisHasTobeTested  & thirdBitTobeChecked;
 if(isBitSet > 0) {
  //Third Bit is set to 1 
 }
```

**Set(1) a particular bit**

```
 int thirdBitTobeSet =   1 << 2    (...0000100)
 int onWhichThisHasTobeSet = 2     (.......010)
 onWhichThisHasTobeSet |= thirdBitTobeSet;
```

**ReSet(0) a particular bit**

```
int thirdBitTobeReSet =   ~(1 << 2)  ; //(...1111011)
int onWhichThisHasTobeReSet = 6      ;//(.....000110)
onWhichThisHasTobeReSet &= thirdBitTobeReSet;
```

**XOR**

Just note that if you perform XOR operation twice, will results the same value.

```
byte toBeEncrypted = 0010 0110
byte salt          = 0100 1011

byte encryptedVal  =  toBeEncrypted ^ salt == 0110 1101
byte decryptedVal  =  encryptedVal  ^ salt == 0010 0110 == toBeEncrypted :)
```

One more logic with XOR is

```
if     A (XOR) B == C (salt)
then   C (XOR) B == A
       C (XOR) A == B
```

The above is useful to swap two variables without temp like below

```
a = a ^ b; b = a ^ b; a = a ^ b;
```

OR

```
a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
```

Comment: Also have look @ Bit manipulation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422259/how-are-integers-internally-represented-at-a-bit-level-in-java/28478572#28478572

Comment: http://sophie-notes.blogspot.in/2013/02/bit-manipulation-tutorial-i.html?showComment=1425557884985

Answer (score 5):

It help to reduce lot of codes. It is occasionally used in RGB values which consist of 8bits.

where 0xff means  **24(0's )  and 8(1's)** like `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`

> It effectively masks the variable so it leaves only the value in the last 8 bits, and ignores all the rest of the bits

It’s seen most in cases like when trying to transform color values from a special format to standard RGB values (which is 8 bits long).

[**Great Explanation See here**](http://blog.oscarliang.net/what-s-the-use-of-and-0xff-in-programming-c-plus-p/)

Answer (score 0):

In 32 bit format system the hexadecimal value `0xff` represents `00000000000000000000000011111111` that is `255(15*16^1+15*16^0)` in decimal. and the bitwise & operator masks the same 8 right most bits as in first operand.

Comment: can you explain a bit more.