# adler32 java bitwise and of input

Tags: java, bitwise-and, adler32

I found the code for adler32 here http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/Adler32-source.html

however my update code looks like following

```
private int a = 1, b = 0;

public void update(byte[] buf, int offset, int len)
{
    for (int i = offset; i < len; i++) {
        a = (a + buf[i]) % MOD_ADLER;
        b = (b + a) % MOD_ADLER;
    }
}
```

as oppose code on the link

```
public void update(byte[] buf, int offset, int len)
{
    for (int i = offset; i < len; i++) {
        a = (a + (buf[i] & 0xff)) % MOD_ADLER;  // <<=== Why & 0xff ?
        b = (b + a) % MOD_ADLER;
    }
}
```

I do not understand need to AND with `0xff` as `buf[i]` is already 8 bytes, I understand it will be promoted to `int` as `a` is `int`, still the type promotion shouldn't change value in `byte`. May be I'm missing some more details as it doesnt work without `& 0xff`, I tested it with the values computed by `java.util.zip.Adler32`

Thanks for the answer, however it will only matter for values that result in negative numbers, for example in my test

```
    byte a = -4;
    int n1 = a & 0xff;
    int n2 = a;
    out.printf(" a %4d %s\n", a,Integer.toBinaryString(a));
    out.printf("n1 %4d %s\n",n1,Integer.toBinaryString(n1));
    out.printf("n2 %4d %s\n",n2,Integer.toBinaryString(n2));
```

prints

```
  a   -4 11111111111111111111111111111100
 n1  252 11111100
 n2   -4 11111111111111111111111111111100
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does value & 0xff do in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `byte` is signed in Java. Hence, the automatic type promotion `byte` -> `int` would always give a integer in the range (-128,127) instead of (0,255), as we want. The `& 0xff` operation fixes that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it will only matter for negative values

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understood the problem. A byte is just an octet of bits, which _can_ be interpreted as an integer (signed or unsigned value). If, for example, the bytes come from a binary file (an executable, an image), and you store them in a Java `byte[]` , about half of them (those with a 1 in the MSB) will be "negative".