# What is this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I found a MySQL Query in my application, which I really don´t understand. Its very long, this is just the part of it, I dont understand:

```
 WHERE ( id & 0xff = 0 ) OR ( ( id >= 3000 ) AND ( id & 0xff != 0xff ) )
```

What the heck is this '0xff'? Threre is no column '0xff' in this table.

Comment: It's just a hexadecimal number.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why is this in the Query? 0xff != 0xff makes no sense at all for me (since its always false....).

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java

Comment: That `&` is not the logical AND, but the binary one!

Comment: I really don´t understand what it is doing exactly. But you are right, I get different results, when I remove the '& 0xff != 0xff' part.

Comment: With parenthesis, you have to read it like `( id & 0xff ) != 0xff`. It basically reduces `id` to the last 8 bits and makes sure, they are not all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xff` binary value is `00000000000000000000000011111111 (under the 32-bit integer)`

If you do a `bitwise AND` with `0xff`, it gives only the value in the `last 8 bits`, all other bites vanishes( because `1 & 0 = 0` and `0 & 0 = 0`)

```
id & 0xff = 0
```

this will check the `last 8 bits are 00000000`;

```
id & 0xff != 0xff
```

this will check the `last 8 bits != 11111111`;