# What is the role of '&' operator in byte to hex conversion?

Tags: java, hex, byte, arrays

While converting byte to hex there is use of '&' operator. I want to know what it does?

```
byte[] b="ABC".getBytes();
System.out.println(b[1] & 0xFF);
```

It gives output 66 as it is ASCII value of 'B'
Any help will be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Answers on the following question might be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java

Comment: It's a bitwise operator - the top answer at stackoverflow.com/questions/17256644/how-does-the-bitwise-and-work-in-java does a pretty good job of explaining what it is

Comment: `getBytes()` probably is not returning ASCII codes. Evaluate [Charset.defaultCharset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--) to find out which character set and encoding is the default for your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code had nothing to do with byte to hex conversion.

`b[1]` can be negative, since bytes in Java have values between -128 and 127.

`b[1] & 0xFF` forces the output to be parsed as a positive integer.

For example, if `b[1]` was equal to -14, `b[1] & 0xFF` would give you 242, since the bit-wise AND is performed after the two arguments are promoted to `int` type, so when you perform `&` with `0xFF`, whose binary representation is `000...00011111111`, you'll always get a positive result.

Comment: nice answer! you might want to mention that if you cast that integer back to a byte it'll be the negative value again!

Comment: Perfect answer.Thank you @Eran.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator (if used on integer-numbers like byte,short,int,long) is the Logic-AND operator. The logic AND-operator works as it follows:

```
  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
& 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
-----------------
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

It is a bit by bit comparison of the binary notation of the 2 numbers. If both of the bits are 1 it will result in 1, otherwise it will result in 0:

```
& || 0 | 1   <- a
===========
0 || 0 | 0
===========
1 || 0 | 1
^
b
```

Comment: While frequent use of '&&' I forgot about '&' operator.Thanks for elaboration.