# I don't know the mean of " i[1]=data[1]& 0xff;"

Tags: java, mysql

the aim of the code  is read data from database,but I don't know the mean of " i[1]=data[1]& 0xff;"   in the getBinaryStream(1) ,what is the '1' mean?

```
 if(rs.next())
            {

                InputStream in=rs.getBinaryStream(1);//what the mean of the code?
                byte[] data = StreamTool.readInputStream(in);

                 int[] i =new int[12];
                 i[1]=data[1]& 0xff;//what the mean of the code?
                 i[4]=data[4]& 0xff;//what the mean of the code?
                 i[7]=data[7]& 0xff;//what the mean of the code?
                 i[10]=data[10]& 0xff;//what the mean of the code?
                 int a=3*(port1-1)+1;
                 int b=3*(port2-1)+1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getBinaryStream() doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream())

> Retrieves the BLOB value designated by this Blob instance as a stream.

**Returns:**

> a stream containing the BLOB data.

The hex literal `0xFF` is an equal int value 255. Java represents `int` as 32 bits.

Binary value of `0xFF`

> 0xFF  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111

[number & 0xff reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java)

The `&` operator performs a `bitwise AND` operation. `data[1]& 0xff` will give you an integer with a bit pattern.

The rule of `&` operator is

> 1&0=0
>
> 1&1=1
>
> 0&0=0
>
> 0&1=0

So when you do a `&` with this `0xFF` on any number, it is going to make `0`s all but leaves only the value in the last 8 bits.

For example, the bitwise AND of `10110111` and `00001101` is `00000101`.

> 10110111
>
> &
>
> 00001101
>
> =
>
> 00000101

Answer (score 1):

You are converting byte data to integer. `“& 0xff”` will effectively masks the variable so it leaves only the value in the last 8 bits, and ignores all the rest of the bits.

Explained very well here,
[What does value & 0xff do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(int)) for getBinaryStream(...)

Now, `data[1]& 0xff` mean, 
here with help of `Bitwise AND operator('&') operation goes to perform.`

More Closely speaking then,

`data[1]& 0xff` means, assume `data[1]` returns some value assume : `255`

and `0xff is hexa-decimal value`,  it's equivalent decimal value is : `255`.

so that finally this operation perform likewise,

```
  255 (11111111)
 &255 (11111111)
----------- 
11111111 : 255(decimal)
```

> Just keep in mind this for Bitwise AND operation,
>
> 1 & 1 = 1
>
> 1 & 0 = 0
>
> 0 & 1 = 0
>
> 0 & 0 = 0

Here, in your case same thing going on, i.e. Bitwise-AND operation.
Let me know if any query.