# Byte to Integer and then to String conversion in Java

Tags: java, integer, byte, tostring

I got a code for MD5 hash generation in Java. It generates the hash in byte array "bytes" and then converts to integer and then to string as follows:

```
byte[] bytes=md.digest(textToHash.getBytes());

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
```

I understood that `bytes[i] & 0xff` converts byte to integer of 32 bit length copying the byte to the least significant byte of the integer:

[What does value & 0xff do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java)

However I couldn't understand what `+ 0x100, 16` does in the parentheses at line 4 of the above code. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking down `Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)`:

- Adding `0x100` (which is 256 decimal) sets the 9th bit to `1`, which guarantees the binary number representation of the result has exactly 9-bits. You could equivalently do `& 0x100`.
- After setting bit 8, the result from the `toString()` will be 9 chars long (of zeroes and ones).
- `substring(1)` effectively ignores bit 8 and outputs the lower 8 bits

So what?

This code puts leading zeroes on values, so all values are exactly 8 binary characters. There's no way to make `Integer.toString()` alone do this.

Comment: Thanks but whats's that ,16?

Comment: `16` is the *radix* - ie base 16, which is hexadecimal. The code basically outputs `1` as `"01"` instead of `"1"`

Comment: thanks. I also found a simpler way on the forums: sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytes[i]));

Comment: @nann yes, using format is the preferred way, but you didn't ask about a better way; you asked "what does this code mean".

Comment: you're right. I just wanted to mention this for those who may read this thread later. Thanks again.