# How does read() api in InputStream works?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to write my input stream which extends InputStream and learnt the following

Input stream is an abstract class which contains abstract methods and implementation for some method it has. Noticed that InputStream contains an abstract method

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException;
```

I'm not very sure about what this method does. So, referred for someother inputstream which extends InputStream and got `FilterInputStream` which extends `InputStream` and the read method implementation in this is like

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    return in.read();
}
```

`in` here refers to the underlying input stream. Consider the constructor of `FilterInputStream` which is like

```
 protected FilterInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
 }
```

In read() method implementation this simply invokes the read method in its parent class which is `InputStream` which is just an abstract method.

1. What read() method in InputStream does?
2. What happens when i invoke the read method of FSDataInputStream?
3. Do we add read() method here just to avoid compilation error? Or do we have any other use with this?

I'm confused with these. Please help me know about it.

Comment: 1. Read the javadoc. 2. Read the javadoc. 3. Read the javadoc. Seriously, read the javadoc. The whole point of an InputStream is to be able to read bytes from a stream of bytes. read() is **the** method doing that: it reads the next byte in the stream of bytes that is an InputStream.

Comment: Read the javadocs @JBNizet still I'm not clear.... If read() method reads the data from input stream how much does it read? will it read entire data from input stream?

Comment: What exactly would input be for if you didn't have a way of reading it?

Comment: Read the javadoc. It says: *Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range  0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.* So it returns 1 byte. It's clearly documented.

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether OP actually read the javadoc, because I can't see how *"Returns: **the next byte** of data"* can be unclear.

Comment: And how can you possibly be implementing an `InputStream` if you don't already have a clear idea of what reading from it means? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I'm just extending it with some additional functionality.. First I have to be clear with methods of `InputStream` so have asked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, @JB Nizet suggested `ByteArrayInputStream` implements the read in a clear way and the code snippet is as follows,

```
public synchronized int read() {
    return (pos < count) ? (buf[pos++] & 0xff) : -1;
}
```

So, this returns the next byte in the buffer which is declared like

```
protected byte buf[];
```

where buf[] is an array of bytes that was provided by the creator of the stream. The elements in the  buffer are the only bytes that can ever be read from the stream; element buf[pos] is the next byte to read.

**Why it returns the result like (buf[pos++] & 0xff)?**

Here is a [nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380077/6680585) which makes us clear on why `value & with 0xff` is done.

ie; to return the result in signed values (between 0 to 255). This converts the unsigned value (byte) to signed value by `&` with `0xff`.

Answer (score 2):

> What read() method in InputStream does?

It reads a byte of data.  It must be implemented by any (non-abstract) subclass of `InputStream`.

In the `FilterInputStream` case, it is implemented by reading from another stream; i.e. the stream that the filter is wrapping.  That stream will be an instance of some subclass of `InputStream` that implements `read()` to actually read data from somewhere.

> What happens when i invoke the read method of FSDataInputStream?

You call end up calling `read()` on the stream that `FSDataInputStream` wraps; i.e. the one passed in the `FSDataInputStream` constructor.

> Do we add read() method here just to avoid compilation error? Or do we have any other use with this?

The purpose of the `read()` method in the `InputStream` API is to be a placeholder for an actual method in an actual stream class.

The purpose of the `read()` method in `FilterInputStream` is to be the actual method.  And it does this by delegating the `read()` call to the next stream in the chain. (Note that in general, `FilterInputStream` has to be subclassed to be useful, and you would expect that the subclass would override at least some of the `read` methods.)

In this case, the `FSDataInputStream` (which is a `FilterInputStream`) acts as an adapter that allows a regular `FSInputStream` to be used as a `DataInputStream`.  For the `read()` method, simple delegation is sufficient.

Comment: Very clearly explained @Stephen would be much happy if you could provide me an example of an underlying stream implementation example which implements this actual `read()` method.

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian *Read the Javadoc.* There are already several examples of exactly that in `java.io`., and Stephen has already named two of them.

Comment: There are lots of them in the Java source code.  You can find some of them here:  http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@6-b14@java%24io@InputStream&k=d . Note that the input stream classes that read stuff from outside of the JVM will end up in calls to `native` methods.  You need the full OpenJDK source code to see the C++ code that implements them.