# How to copy bytes in JSONArray to Byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am getting image data in the form of buffer(bytes), but I want to convert it into a base64 string. The data is received inside a JSONArray, like so

```
JSONArray : `[53,57,51,47,53,57,51,55,50,98,98,54,53,51,54,97,102,101,53,101,102,54,57,54,53,54,53,51,102,98,53,99,98,98,99,51,98,48,52,57,56,52,52,101,54,48,50,99,56,55,101,54,53,97,51,102,56,49,56,57,56,98,102,56,49,57,97,57]`
```

For that I am copying the JSONArray into `"byte" array`, like so :

```
JSONArray bytearray_json = record.getJSONObject("image").getJSONArray("data");
byte[] bytes = new byte[bytearray_json.length()];
for (int i =0; i < bytearray_json.length(); i++ ) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)bytearray_json.get(i);
}
String base_64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But I get an exception : `Cannot cast Integer to byte`
I cannot do `bytearray_json.get(i).toString().getBytes();` since it returns a `Byte Array`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `bytes[i] = (byte)(int)bytearray_json.get(i)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this out to,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("image").getJSONArray("data");
byte[] bytes = new byte[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        bytes[i]=(byte)(((int)jsonArray.get(i)) & 0xFF);
}
 Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: would you like to elaborate why it needs `& 0xFF` ?

Comment: Well, there are mainly two reasons to use this `& 0xFF`,

1. To mask the value to get only last 8 bits, and ignores all the rest of the bits.

2. In this case, we are trying to deal with RGB values which is exactly 8 bits long.

You can read more [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hasangi for your answer.

For those of you who wants to use a more modern answer, based on Kotlin:

```
fun JSONArray.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val byteArr = ByteArray(length())
    for (i in 0 until length()) {
        byteArr[i] = (get(i) as Int and 0xFF).toByte()
    }
    return byteArr
}
```

and to use:

```
val bytes = jsonObj.getJSONArray("bytes").toByteArray()
```