# Why is & 0xff applied to a byte variable

Tags: java, byte, logical-operators, one-time-password

Why is `& 0xff` applied to a byte variable in the reference implementation of the time-based OTP (TOTP, RFC 6238)? In my opinion, this does not change the value since the byte data type has a length of 8 bits.

```
byte[] hash = hmac_sha(crypto, k, msg);
int offset = hash[hash.length - 1] & 0xf;

int binary =
  ((hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
  ((hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) |
  ((hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) |
  (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

int otp = binary % DIGITS_POWER[codeDigits];
```

Besides, what is the reason to apply the `XAND` operator to the first element with `0x7f`? It can still result in a number with 10 digits, which is larger than the largest entry in `DIGITS_POWER`, which is `100 000 000`.

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238, page 13)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java, but you've actually asked two questions here: one about the utility of `& 0xFF` and another about why this code is clearing the most-significant bit with `& 0x7F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal `0xff` is, as per the JLS, of type `int`.
Also as per the JLS, when an operation is performed between a `byte` and and `int`, the `byte` is safely *widened* to an `int` and the result is an `int`.

What this means is that the expression:

```
hash[offset + 1] & 0xff
```

Is more or less the same as:

```
(int)(hash[offset + 1]) & 0xff
```

In fact, an `int` is needed as the result type for the following bit-shift operation to make sense.

```
(hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16
```

If the bit-shift was done on a `byte`, the bits would just rotate back to their original position (16 being an exact multiple of 8).

The whole code is constructing an `int` from a `byte[]`.

The odd mask `0x7f` used on the high byte is used instead of `0xff` to mask off the left-most (or most significant) bit, which is the *sign bit*, to ensure the final result is not negative.

Comment: So what would happen without the `& 0xff` here? Would the byte value be widened to `int` with a sign extension?

Comment: I think you were editing the answer to answer my question while I was typing my question. 8v)

Comment: @Fred if you didn't perform the bitwise AND, and instead just cast each `byte` directly to an `int`, you would get negative numbers being bit-shifted. While this doesn't necessarily cause a problem except for 1 bit of the hash being lost 1/2 of the time, the requirement could be that all implementations should not have this side effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte b = -5;
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
```

This produces the following output:

```
-5
251
```

When `&` is executed, both operands first get promoted to 32 bits. `-5` is represented as `11111111111111111111111111111011`, while `0xFF` is just '24 zeroes and 8 ones on the end', so `(-5) & 0xFF` gives `11111011` (leading zeroes omitted).

Answer (score 1):

The operation does change the value. `byte & 0xff` converts the byte, which is signed, to an int representing an unsigned value corresponding to the byte's bit pattern.