# Don't understand how these bitwise operators operate on bytes and integers

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am working with some code that takes in a binary file as input. However, I am having trouble understanding the for loop in the code, as I don't understand what the bitwise operators do to `IFD_Address`, such as the `|=`, `<<`, and `& 0xff`. I think `IFD_Address` refers to a pointer in the binary file, but I am not sure. What is this piece of code trying to achieve?

```
byte[] IFD_Address_tmp = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 4, 8); 
int IFD_Address = 0;
int i = 0;
int shiftBy = 0;
for (shiftBy = 0; shiftBy < 32; shiftBy += 8) {
    IFD_Address |= ((long) (IFD_Address_tmp[i] & 0xff)) << shiftBy;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It is packing 4 bytes into a single int.

Comment: The same thing could be achieved with `int IFD_Address = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 4, 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();`, which is clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: If you don't understand what they do, did you try looking them up in documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is best understood in terms of moving bits around, not numbers. Bytes comprise eight bits, integers, 32 bits. The loop basically takes each byte in the array and places the corresponding bits in the integer `IFD_Address` in 8-bit chunks, from right (least significant) to left (most significant), like this:

[image]

About the bitwise operations:

- `& 0xff` is required to [capture the 8 bits into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11380062/11595728);
- `<<` shifts the bits to the left to select the appropriate place in `IFD_Address`;
- `|=` sets the bits in `IFD_Address`.

See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for details.