# Why java.io.InputStream `read()` method outputs different value if compared with `read(byte[] b)`?

Tags: java, websocket

My goal is to decode message, sent by a client to the server through the WebSocket connection. The frame data have length, more on Base Framing Protocol [RFC6455].

I recently found out that `read(byte[] b)` outputs the entire frame.

For example, when a client send message `abcdef` to the server

```
byte[] frame = new byte[1000]
inputStream.read(frame); // [[-127, -122, -69, -122, 95, -5, -38, -28, 60, -97, -34, -32, 0, 0, ....]
```

However, the first byte should be `129` and the second byte should be `134`. Is the only way to read the frame is through loop and use `int[]` instead of `byte[]` since the `read()` method outputs int instead of byte?

```
int[] frame = new frame[1000];
booean close = false;

frame[0] = inputStream.read();
frame[1] = inputStream.read();

int length = frame[1] & 127;

int pointer = 2;

while (!close) {
  frame[pointer] = inputStream.read();
  if (pointer == length) {
    close = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Java bytes can't be 129 or 134. That's out of range.

Comment: @Tom I thought 8 bit range is between 0 - 255. Is the penalty performance of using int negligible?

Comment: That range is correct, for unsigned ranges. For singed ranges it is -128 - 127 and that's the range for byte here. Also see [Why is the range of bytes -128 to 127 in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3621067)

Comment: The `read()` method returns `int` only because it needs to be able to return all valid byte values _and a sentinel value for EOF_. Using an `int` means the byte values are 0-255 and the sentinel value is -1. But the `read(byte[])` method returns the _number of_ bytes read, not the actual read bytes. The read bytes are placed in the `byte[]` array, which is an array of `byte`. In Java, all number primitives (except `char`?) are signed. That means the range of a `byte` is -128-127. But the values are still the "same" (e.g. -1 signed is 255 unsigned).

Answer (score 2):

-127 'is' 129, i.e. it's 10000001, which is either number depending on whether it's signed or unsigned.

Read [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) for more details on the format of signed binary numbers.

So you could use byte[] and convert bytes to int when you need to, e.g.

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        byte b = -127;
        int i = b & 0xff;
        System.out.println("b = " + b + " i = " + i);
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it why `10000001` that gets AND-ing with `11111111` becomes `129`?

Comment: @kidfrom See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java