# How fast calculate MODULUS for divisor greater than 8, 16, 32

Tags: vb.net, modulus

I´m trying to make very fast MOD operations.
I saw in several pages we can do alternatively calculate the MOD using the AND operator with (Divisor-1).  Eg.:

result = (100 mod 8)     is the same as
  result = (100 and 7)

It functions perfectly if the divisor is less than 8 bits, but if we calculate (1245 mod 67) we can see the result is different of (1245 and 66).

So, how can I calculate this faster than using the MOD operator provided by VB.NET language?

Thanks!

Comment: This method of calculating MOD works for 2^n, but I don't believe it works for non-powers of 2 (e.g. 8 MOD 6 = 2, but 8 AND 5 = 0).

Comment: Are you sure there's a performance bottleneck on the MOD operator?

Comment: Thank you for answers. If we consider the positives 2^N numbers, yes, we have a good improvement related to MOD. But since the tip just function to "power of 2" numbers, I have to consider the MOD instruction as the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a bitwise `AND` only works for modulus powers of 2 (and only positive ones, at that).  It does not work for other numbers.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator)

I think that the modulus operator built into the framework is fast and you probably won't be able to improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `100 mod 8` = `100 and 7` works, because 7 is binary `111b`.

Whatever number you have (100 decimal is `1100100b`), the last 3 binary digits (bits) are kept due to the `111b`. For 100, that would be `100b` = 4.

Now consider what you did attempt with 1245 mod 67.

1245 is binary `10011011101b`.

67 is binary `1000011b`.

Can you see, why it's not working?