# Write a method called isOdd() in a class called OddTest, which takes an int as an argument and returns true if the int is odd

Tags: java

I'm in my first year of Java and am having trouble with with a boolean method to test if even or odd. I have most of the code, but when I enter an odd number it returns it as even. My professor gave us the signature of the method: `public static boolean isOdd(int number)`

```
package homeWork1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddTest {

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int number;
      System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      number = input.nextInt();
      isOdd(number);

      boolean answer=isOdd(number);
      if (answer=true)
      {
          System.out.println("EVEN");
      }

      if (answer=false)
      {
          System.out.println("ODD");
      }



   }
   public static boolean isOdd(int number)
   { 
    if(number % 2 == 0)
   {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: If it is `%2 == 0` that means it is even... So instead `return false` if that statement is true. else `return true` something like this...  `if( (number%2) == 0) { return true;} else {return false;}`

Comment: @James, please mark one of the answers to your question as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

`if (number % 2 == 0)` means that the number is divisible by 2, and therefore it is even.

You want to change your condition to:

```
if (number % 2 != 0)
```

And, as a conditional statement is a boolean value, you can simplify it further like:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int number)
    return number % 2 != 0;
}
```

Also, you have an error in the code that uses your method.

```
  boolean answer=isOdd(number);
  if (answer=true)
  {
      System.out.println("ODD");
  }

  if (answer=false)
  {
      System.out.println("EVEN");
  }
```

Here, `answer=true` is an assignment, not comparison. You can fix it by writing:

```
if (isOdd(number))
{
    System.out.println("ODD");
}

else
{
    System.out.println("EVEN");
}
```

Comment: better to use (number&1)==1 . Try isOdd(0x80000000)

Comment: @ddyer I should like to challlenge that. `number % 2 != 0` is much more readable, which should always be your first choice. Besides, I see no other advantage in `(number & 1) == 1`.

Comment: number&1 is much faster.  1 cycle on most machines vs many cycles for division with remainder.  Handwave about pipelining and smart compilers may help you though.  The other thing is that the division may throw a number exception if the dividend is 0x80000000.

Comment: @ddyer it will work [only with powers of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072710/5922757). As the OP seems to be a beginner programmer, it might make him only more confused about what's going on. Also, JVM is smart, I think it can optimize it out by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether *answer* is true or false, you're assigning these values. Checking for equality is `==` in Java. By the way, I'd recommend using just `if (answer)` and `if (!answer)` for booleans - looks simpler and less room for a mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything works properly now. Tired eyes didn't catch the ==

Comment: @JamesSeeley you might also want to rename *isOdd* method to *isEven* (or invert the return values and corresponding checks) as it's doing the opposite