# What is the difference between hash()%n and n%hash()

Tags: java, hash, hashcode, hash-collision

In many books, syllabus, tutorials I've seen that a good option to find a proper cell of an item is to calculate a number of the cell: `item.hash()%(n-1) = # of the  bucket.`

But why is this certain expression is mentioned?

How does the inverse one `(n-1)%item.hash() = # of the  bucket` differs from it?

P.S. I know that Java HashMap uses `(n - 1) & hash`, I would like only to catch the difference in sparsing key between these two approaches.

Comment: Did you mean (n-1) **%** item.hash() or (n-1) **&** item.hash()?

Comment: Where do you get that *inverse* code from? Why should it be the number of buckets? It computes something completely different. `5 % 11 = 5` while `11 % 5 = 1`. Modulo is **not** commutative.

Comment: Think of the `%` operator as computing the remainder after dividing the left argument by the right. This operator is not symmetric in its arguments. You wouldn't expect that the remainder of, say, 12/5 to be the same as the remainder of 5/12, would you? The `&` operator, on the other hand, is symmetric in its arguments.

Comment: Also see [Bitwise and in place of modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of operator modulus `%` as a way to *distribute* uniformly a set of numbers through *reducing* them over a smaller range. The set of numbers are, of corse, the hashcodes of input keys. The small range is the capacity of the table.

This is a useful technique when you want to assign an index in a small table to store a high number.

The inverse operation sounds quite weird (and useless): Taking in account that the hash codes are high numbers and n is small, `n % hash` would return always `n`, so it has no interest at all.

Java choses indexes through `hash & (length-1)`, indeed, which is not aritmetically equivalent to `hash % length`, but it is an alternative -and cheaper than modulus- formula to reduce and distribute (credits to @Zabuza).

Comment: And `hash & (length-1)` is equivalent to `(length-1) & hash` since `&` (bitwise and) is commutative. So maybe OP read `hash % length` vs `(length - 1) & hash`, or any other similar combination.

Comment: @Zabuza Right. The difference is lying over the `-1`.

Comment: Note that `%` is not always the same as `&`. In Javas code it works, obviously. But only due to how its done. See [Bitwise and in place of modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator).

Answer (score 2):

> How does the inverse one (n-1)%item.hash() = # of the  bucket differs from it?

Basically it doesn't work.

That expression needs to reduce the hash code to a value in the range 0 .. n - 1, so that it can be used as a subscript for an array of size n.

But the "inverse" function doesn't do that.  So if you tried to use it, the (alleged) bucket subscripts would give exceptions since h % (n - 1) > (n - 1) or < 0 for most values of h in the range of the Java `int` type.

As @Zubuza notes remainder (%) and division (/) are not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `hash % n` vs `n % hash` is that `hash % n` is going to be a lot more distributed than `n % hash`.

`n % hash` will almost always be equivalent to `n`, because `a % b` where `b > a` is equal to `a` (E.g. `15 % 30 = 15`).

[I created a graph to show the differences](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5x2njsepbw) (red is `x % n` and blue is `n % x` where `x` represents the hash).
[image: Graph]

The idea in java is to avoid the '[expensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues)' `%` (mod) operation and instead do the comparably cheap `&` (and) operation. But that only works when `n` is a power of 2. So a Java HashMap always uses a power of 2 for the number of buckets.

Comment: "HashMap always uses a power of 2 for the number of buckets". Good to know. Thanks.