# Check whether an integer is a multiple of a number using bitwise operators

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given integers **n** and **m**, how can I determine that **n** is a multiple of **m** using bitwise operators, without any fancy `n % m == 0`?

Comment: It's quite easy if m is a power of 2. Otherwise it's quite challenging.

Comment: I know that m is even

Comment: If `m` is a constant then it can be done with a multiplication and a bitwise rotate, but multiplication is hardly bitwise.. and if `m` is a variable it doesn't work out that well (it's still possible but requires a dozen extra multiplies)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise and in place of modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator)

Comment: There is no easy way. You may want to refer to the referenced links in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19760152/1112010.