# Optimizing a%16 using bitswise operations

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

How can I optimize `int a = b % 16` using bitwise operations? Tried with >> 4 but I am missing something.

Comment: `int a = b & 0xf;`

Comment: highly likely that the compiler will optimize this for you anyway (if you compile with optimizations turned on), there is absolutely no need for you to do it manually

Comment: When you look at a number like `1234` and you want to know that number **mod 100** you can simply read off the last two digits to get `34`.  Similarly, in binary, if you want to know the number mod some-power-of-two, you can read off (mask off) the last n bits. assuming you're doing mod (2^n). (as Iłya Bursov has shown)

Comment: What make you think bitwise operations are more efficient than modulo division? They might be in assembly but in C++ if a modulo division can efficiently be turned into bitwise operations then the compiler will do it for you (at least if you enable optimisations). Compilers are smart.

Comment: Compile with `-O2` or `-O3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitwise and in place of modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator)

Comment: Handy reading: [The as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). TL;DR version: don't think of code as a list of instructions you want the computer to perform, think of it as a description of behaviour that the compiler will transform into the most efficient list of instructions that it can.

Comment: `b >> 4` is not equivalent to `b % 16`.  It is equivalent to `b / 16`.  (Assuming unsigned)

Comment: Beware that n & 0xf and n % 16 will give different results for negative n.

Comment: Trust the optimizer.  Compiler optimizers are truly incredibly amazing.  Write the code for legibility.  If `% 16` is the correct thing to convey to a reader of the code, then use `% 16`.  If `& 0xF` is the correct thing to convey, in the context, then use that.  **Profile**, to find if there are bottlenecks that need to be hand-optimized.  Never hand-optimize without profiling, because otherwise you won't know if the inscrutable code is any better than the straightforward code (and may actually be worse).

Comment: And use unsigned types where possible as they can be optimized better.